# How I can speed up mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a crawler which consits of 6+ processes. Half of processes are masters which crawl web and when they find jobs they put it inside `jobs` collection. In most times masters save 100 jobs at once (well I mean they get 100 jobs and save each one of them separatly as fast as possible.

The second half of processes are slaves which constantly check if new jobs of some type are available for him - if yes it marks them `in_process` (it is done using findOneAndUpdate), then processe the job and save the result in another collection.

Moreover from time to time master processes have to read a lot of data from `jobs` table to synchronize.

So to sum up there are a lot of read operations and write operations on db. When db was small it was working ok but now when I have ~700k job records (job document is small, it has 8 fields and has proper indexes / compound indexes) my db slacks. I can observe it when displaying "stats" page which basicaly executes ~16 `count` operations with some conditions (on indexed fields).

When masters/slaves processes are not runing stats page displays after 2 seconds. When masters/slaves are runing same page displays around 1 minute and sometime is does not display at all (timeout).

So how I can make my db to handle more requests per second? I have to replicate it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That does not help his issue at all. Unfortunately I have no answer for you as well, but your issue does seem like something mongodb was built for, perhaps asking the creators until someone posts an answer would be in your favor. good luck!

Comment: @Discipol: what I meant to say is maybe OP should do less work? That would speed things up. It's hard to give more concrete answer with this amount of information. I feel that the whole architecture needs to be reviewed.

Comment: OP: what is the issue again? The slow rendering of stats page on which you are running 16 `count` operations against already busy collections? Don't do that then. Maybe precalculation can help you here (that is, maintain counters separately).

Comment: Also, I question the choice of the database. MongoDB with its db-level write lock is hardly the best choice for this scenario. Maybe some MVCC store would fare better.

Comment: Well I selected mongo as I store many metadata which differ for each executed/parsed job. Maybe you are right and I should keep jobs in one database and parsed data in mongo for example.

Comment: We also faced such issues. Can you give more detail how mongo is deployed? First are you having enough connections for application to process? Are you using sharding?

Comment: Well I just installed mongo on VPS with ubuntu. I dont use replica set/sharding just single mongod instance. What do you mean by `enough connections`? What do you suggest?